# Change TabBarItem title font to bold in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to set the font weight of a selected tab bar item to bold font. It seems as it has no effect. Any idea what is wrong. `forState: .Normal` works as expected,  `forState: .Selected` has no effect.

```
let tabBarItem0 = tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem
var selectedImage0 : UIImage = UIImage(named:"ic_tabbar_item_one")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
var fontLight:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 12)!
var fontBold:UIFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)!

tabBarItem0.image = unselectedImage0
tabBarItem0.selectedImage = selectedImage0
tabBarItem0.title = "Overview"
tabBarItem0.setTitleTextAttributes(
    [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: fontLight
    ], forState: .Normal)

tabBarItem0.setTitleTextAttributes(
    [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: fontBold
    ], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your state of tabBarItem turns into `Selected`?

Comment: No I'm not. How can I check that?

Comment: had you found the solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: The best solution I have found is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234671/changing-selected-tabbaritem-font-ios

Answer (score 6):

### **FOUND THE SOLUTION** (Swift 3, XCode 8.1)

1. **In Storyboard, give a unique Tag to each UITabBarItem you have:** For every tab -> Select it and go to it's "Attributes Inspector" -> Give each one a **unique** number in the "Tag" field but you should not use zero (I used 1 through 4).

   *This sets us up for later, to identify which tab is pressed.*

---

2. **Create a new subclass of UITabBarController and then assign it**: FILE -> New File -> iOS Cocoa Touch -> create a Subclass of UITabBarController. Assign the new .swift file to your
   UITabBarController under "Identity Inspector."

   *We will need custom logic in our UITabBarController.*

---

3. **Create a new subclass of UITabBarItem, assign the same file to all of your UITabBarItems**: FILE -> New File -> iOS Cocoa Touch -> create a Subclass of UITabBarItem and assign the same one to all of your tabs.

   *We will need a shared custom logic in our tab bar items.*

---

4. **Add this code to your UITabBarItem subclass**, it sets up the initial state (primary tab bold, the rest unselected) and will allow for programmatic tab changes as well:

   ```
   class MyUITabBarItemSubclass: UITabBarItem {

       //choose initial state fonts and weights here
       let normalTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightRegular) 
       let selectedTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightBold)

       //choose initial state colors here
       let normalTitleColor = UIColor.gray 
       let selectedTitleColor = UIColor.black

       //assigns the proper initial state logic when each tab instantiates 
       override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()

           //this tag # should be your primary tab's Tag* 
           if self.tag == 1 { 
               self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: selectedTitleFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: selectedTitleColor], for: UIControlState.normal)
           } else {
               self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: normalTitleFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: normalTitleColor], for: UIControlState.normal)
           }

       }

   }
   ```

*Here we set up the initial state so that the tabs are set correctly when the app opens up, we'll take care of the physical tab presses in the next subclass.*

---

5. **Add this code to your UITabBarController subclass**, it's the logic for assigning the correct states as you press on the tabs.

   ```
   class MyUITabBarControllerSubclass: UITabBarController {

       //choose normal and selected fonts here
       let normalTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
       let selectedTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightBold)

       //choose normal and selected colors here
       let normalTitleColor = UIColor.gray
       let selectedTitleColor = UIColor.black


       //the following is a delegate method from the UITabBar protocol that's available 
       //to UITabBarController automatically. It sends us information every
       //time a tab is pressed. Since we Tagged our tabs earlier, we'll know which one was pressed,
       //and pass that identifier into a function to set our button states for us

       override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
           setButtonStates(itemTag: item.tag)
       }


       //the function takes the tabBar.tag as an Int
       func setButtonStates (itemTag: Int) {

           //making an array of all the tabs
           let tabs = self.tabBar.items

           //looping through and setting the states
           var x = 0
           while x < (tabs?.count)! {

               if tabs?[x].tag == itemTag {
                   tabs?[x].setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: selectedTitleFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: selectedTitleColor], for: UIControlState.normal)
               } else {
                   tabs?[x].setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: normalTitleFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: normalTitleColor], for: UIControlState.normal)
               }

               x += 1

           }

       }

   }
   ```

*It looks like this was such a pain because for some reason the tabs do not recognize state changes into ".Selected". We had to do everything by working with .Normal states only - basically detecting the state changes ourselves.*

---

6. **You can programmatically change the tabs and still detect state changes by...** I'll update this later if anyone has an interest, just ask.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
        [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"your_font_name", size:11)!, 
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(rgb: 0x929292)], 
        forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: This doesn't change the font for me for `.selected` state.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue when tried to change font of selected item. Looks like titleTextAttributes' font parameter is only useful when setting them to normal state. That's why I implemented `UITabBarControllerDelegate` where I update attributes for currently selected item. You should call `updateSelection()` method after `UITabBarController`s `loadView()` too. Or you can call `updateSelection()` method in overridden `selectedItem` setter.

```
extension TabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    updateSelection()
  }

  func updateSelection() {
    let normalFont = Fonts.Lato.light.withSize(10)
    let selectedFont = Fonts.Lato.bold.withSize(10)
    viewControllers?.forEach {
      let selected = $0 == self.selectedViewController
      $0.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: selected ? selectedFont : normalFont], for: .normal)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly on iOS 11.4, states getting mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

**Build Settings\Swift Language Version: 4.1**

**General\Deployment Target: 10.3**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let attrsNormal = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
                 NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)!]
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal,
                                                     for: UIControlState.normal)

    let attrsSelected = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
                       NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)!]
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attrsSelected,
                                                     for: UIControlState.selected)
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I try to change font of selected tab by using UITabBarItem but it doesn't work. Adoption of delegate is suggested to get informed when tab changes. I just put pieces together.

```swift
private class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }

    override func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, animated: Bool) {
        super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: animated)
        updateTabBarAppearance()
    }
}

extension MyTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        updateTabBarAppearance()
    }

    func updateTabBarAppearance() {
        self.tabBar.tintColor = .red
        let unselectedLabelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .regular)
        let selectedLabelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
        let labelColor = UIColor.init(red: 38/255.0, green: 38/255.0, blue: 38/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let selectedIconColor = UIColor.init(red: 8/255.0, green: 8/255.0, blue: 8/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        viewControllers?.forEach {
            let isSelected = $0 == self.selectedViewController
            let selectedFont = isSelected ? selectedLabelFont : unselectedLabelFont
            $0.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: selectedFont, .foregroundColor: labelColor], for: .normal)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @HapiNguyen! Can you please edit your post to explain why/how your solution answers the OPs question?

Comment: Hi @otolock, yes sure, I hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the state of `tabBarItem0` is not changed to `Selected`. Because this is `UITabBarItem` which represents a single element of a `UITabBar`. So, you can not directly change the status using `UITabBarItem` API. You have to change it state by assigning `selectedItem`.

This information is gained from documentation and I suggest all programmers to have skills like this. Hopefully, this will help.

Comment: `setItems` is setting the items to the tabbar and is used when you want to add, remove or reorder items in the tabbar. This has nothing to do, at least for my understanding, with the select state: https://goo.gl/LfEIKH

Comment: I just update the answer. You should assign to the `selectedItem` property of `UITabBar`. @ThomasKremmel

Answer (score 1):

To set the `TitleTextAttribute`, you should use the `appearance` proxy like: `[UIBarItem appearance]`

Comment: He is asking why the appearance did not change. Not asking how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I know that is what he is asking. I believe the reason is that it is not being set correctly.

Comment: But the `appearance` is set for the whole app, he probably just wants to set it in this particular case I assume? I think last two lines of codes are correct, it's just not changing to the correct state. Any ideas? @rmp

Comment: Per the docs: "In iOS v5.0 and later, you can customize the appearance of tab bars by setting item label text attributes using appearance selectors declared by UIBarItem. "

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But that will apply for every single `UIBarItem`. And I don't say you are wrong. It's just the last two lines of codes are correct as well. The problem is he does not know how to change it to `Selected` status. @rmp

Comment: The last two lines of code are not correct, if they were the OP's code would work and there would not have been a post.  Also nowhere in the OP does is state that it is for a single Tab, just that when a tab is selected. It would seem odd to not apply the bold selected state to all tabs.  Let's just agree to disagree as this is not constructive.

Comment: I think both of your answers are not correct ;-) The docs say "you can customize the title’s text attributes using setTitleTextAttributes:forState:, either for a single item, or for all items by using the appearance proxy " . Thus setting it for a single item as I do is fine. https://goo.gl/oX5KW4

Comment: I even tried it using the `appearance` proxy from `UIBarItem`. Same effect -> no result. I start to consider this to be a Simulator bug. Will try it on real hardware. `UIBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes( [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),NSFontAttributeName: fontBold], forState: UIControlState.Selected)`